# Launching jar via sh script works normally but via crontab gives ClassFormatError

Tags: java, linux, shell, cron, shellexecute

Launching the jar via a java -cp command in an shell scrip eg: RunFileConverter.sh file on linux works *without a problem*. But, when I try to execute the script via 'crontab -e' it gives me a ClassFormatError.

The jar was compiled on Win7 with the Java 6 jdk (latest) and the java version on the (redhat) linux server is also JRE 6 (1.6.0_29).

owner of the files is pipe, and the crontab is launched via same user.

Contents of the RunFileConverter.sh:

```
java -cp /home/pipe/Custom/cbs/:/home/pipe/Custom/cbs/FileConverter.jar fileconverter.Launcher
```

Filestructure (/home/pipe/Custom/cbs/):
    lib/somelib.jar
    FileConverter.jar
    FileConverter.properties
    RunFileConverter.sh
    fileconverter.log

Stripped down Launching class file:

```
package fileconverter;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Launcher {

    // logger
    public final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FileConverter.LOGFILE);

    /**
     * Main class
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // logger handlers, properties etc ...
        Handler fileHandler;
        // ...


        // create converters
        FileConverter requestConverter = new RequestFileConverter();
        FileConverter exportConverter = new ExportFileConverter();

        // start ya conversions, aarrr mate
        requestConverter.run();
        exportConverter.run();

    }
}
```

crontab-e

```
*/5 * * * * /home/pipe/Custom/cbs/RunFileConverter.sh
```

I have no idea what the error might be

Comment: that's the problem when you code with headphone on. :)

Comment: Launch 'java -version' from crontab and be sure that it uses JRE 6 too. You might put whole path to java binary. Maybe you have jre 5 somwhere and crontab is picking it. It might be also a permission problem - ClassFormatError suggests that class file is not readable.

Comment: Jep, different version picked up by crontab too! A thx for you too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely cron does have different (older) version of `java` in path.

What does it say if you execute `java -version` via cron?